# package.install with custom lib cannot load packages

Tags: r, install.packages

I'm trying to **install R packages with dependencies** to a **custom lib** location. Here's the minimal example script (`req.R`):

```
dir.create("r_packages")
install.packages("R.utils", lib="r_packages")
library("R.utils", character.only = TRUE, lib.loc="r_packages")
```

Running this with `Rscript` (e.g. in the [r-base docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base/)) shows, that the **install** is running **fine**, but **loading** the packages **fails**:

*Output shortened. Full paste is [here](https://pastebin.com/QwXtsr59)*

```sh
$ Rscript req.R
also installing the dependencies ‘R.oo’, ‘R.methodsS3’

[...]

* installing *source* package ‘R.methodsS3’ ...
[...]
* DONE (R.methodsS3)
* installing *source* package ‘R.oo’ ...
[...]
* DONE (R.oo)
* installing *source* package ‘R.utils’ ...
[...]
* DONE (R.utils)

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpU4nBhU/downloaded_packages’
Error: package ‘R.oo’ required by ‘R.utils’ could not be found
Execution halted
```

**Loading** the packages **one by one** in reverse order of dependency **works fine**:

```sh
$ cat req.R
dir.create("r_packages")
#install.packages("R.utils", lib="r_packages")
library("R.methodsS3", character.only = TRUE, lib.loc="r_packages")
library("R.oo", character.only = TRUE, lib.loc="r_packages")
library("R.utils", character.only = TRUE, lib.loc="r_packages")


$ Rscript req.R
Warning message:
In dir.create("r_packages") : 'r_packages' already exists
R.methodsS3 v1.7.1 (2016-02-15) successfully loaded. See ?R.methodsS3 for help.
R.oo v1.22.0 (2018-04-21) successfully loaded. See ?R.oo for help.

Attaching package: ‘R.oo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:

    getClasses, getMethods

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    attach, detach, gc, load, save

R.utils v2.8.0 successfully loaded. See ?R.utils for help.

Attaching package: ‘R.utils’

The following object is masked from ‘package:utils’:

    timestamp

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    cat, commandArgs, getOption, inherits, isOpen, parse, warnings
```

Anyone with a hint into the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found, that setting the standard library path with `.libPaths()` solved the problem. Obviously, the `library()` function does not pass the `lib.loc` argument to succeeding calls.

This is the final code:

```
dir.create("r_packages")
.libPaths(c("r_packages"))
install.packages("R.utils", lib="r_packages")
library("R.utils", character.only = TRUE, lib.loc="r_packages")
```